# What C# 4.0 features can be used while still targeting the .NET 3.5 runtime?

Tags: c#

With C# 3.0 you could use many of its features (object initializers, var variables, lambda expressions) while still targeting .NET 2.0 or 3.0.

What new C# 4.0 features can be used while still targeting the .NET 2.0, 3.0 or 3.5 runtimes?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Can I use all C# 4.0 features in a project that targets .Net 3.5?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3517172/can-i-use-all-c-4-0-features-in-a-project-that-targets-net-3-5)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

- Dynamic features: Probably not. I suppose they COULD implement the dynamic features without the DLR, but that doesn't seem likely.
- New generic constraints: The CLR supports them
- Optional and named: CLR already supports it (VB-style)

Update: I just heard that C# 4 compiler will not support anything under 4.0 framework.

Comment: You could support the non-DLR based dynamic features the same way VB does.

Comment: Yes, but that'd require them to target DLR and the VB way. It's possible, but then C# would end up acting different on different targets.